# gltf objects problem with apache htaccess pretty link rules

Tags: .htaccess, gltf

I am using gltf objects on my website with three.js. And I am using pretty links rules on my htaccess file. If I browse this url : https://yeni.elbielectric.com/gett.php my object is loading and appearing on page. But if I browse this url : https://yeni.elbielectric.com/urunler/zena/silverline/fildisi/anahtar/ object is loading but not disappearing. And I cannot see any console error. I think beacuse of htaccess rules there is a problem. Here is my htaccess content :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteRule ^urunler/$  products.php    [NC,L]  

RewriteRule ^urunler/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$    product-detail.php?prdname=$1&prddetail=$2&prdcolor=$3&functype=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$    product-detail.php?prdname=$1&prddetail=$2&prdcolor=$3&functype=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^urunler/(.*)/(.*)$    product-list.php?prdname=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$    product-list.php?prdname=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

there are some paths about my 3d objects and texture on js code. I think there is a problem about them.

for example : "../../../../../Models/ZenaVega/zena.gltf"

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^urunler/?$  products.php  [NC,L]  

RewriteRule ^(?:urunler|products)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$    product-detail.php?prdname=$1&prddetail=$2&prdcolor=$3&functype=$4 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(?:urunler|products)/([^/]*)/?$  product-list.php?prdname=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @Lovestoned, Could you please do give me sample/test url which you are hitting and what error you are getting?